# Dynamic field based on nid

Tags: nodes

I'm building a website for ads. Every ad will have an option to become a VIP ad and will be displayed in a blocks with better position. 
The users will be able to make their ad into VIP ad by sending an SMS with prefix and their ad nid.

The idea is when a user clicks on the link "Make this ad VIP" will be displaying a field with details how to make the regular ad into VIP content. Let's say the ad node has nid 100, so when the user clicks on "Make this ad VIP" a info will be displayed like this: Send a text message "Prefix100" to the number 2xxx..where 100 will be the node id. On other ad if the node ID is 200, after clicking on "Make this ad VIP" the display text should be: Send a text message "Prefix200" to the number 2xxx.
The module for SMS service is already created.

The field with details will be hidden and "Make this ad VIP" will be a toggle, so I'll use jQuery for that, but how can I set the node id on every node?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Every node has a node ID by design already. Perhaps you could clarify this question?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've just figured out how to achieve this. I'm using Display suite and I've created a custom field like this: Send a text message SPORT[node:nid] to number 2xxx .... The key was the token [node:nid]. It's working great.